# Trim Issue With VBA

Tags: vba, excel, trim

So the below code works sometimes and sometimes it adds the ampersand (to the copy buffer) which I am trying to cut out of the text string.

The point of the code is to copy the string from the right position up to before the ampersand. However, in random scenarios it still adds the ampersand.

```
Private Sub Block1_Enter()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim MyData As New DataObject
    Dim this As String
    Dim oldxt As String
    oldtxt = Block1.Text
    If InStr(Block1.Text, "&") > 0 Then
        this = Trim(Right(Block1.Text, InStr(Block1.Text, "&") - 1))
        Block1.Text = "End Date Copied" & this
        MyData.SetText this
        MyData.PutInClipboard
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
        Block1.Text = oldtxt
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

can someone try and explain why it sometimes works and sometimes doesnt? Below is an image with the two examples of where it doesnt work correctly

*(Note for clarification: the textbox values shown below are the **source** values, not the results)*

[image]

Comment: They all have `&`? Confused to your goal.

Comment: edited original post so that its more clear

Comment: the image is to reference two examples of why it didnt work- if the textbox display happens to be a part of the issue

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell which examples don't work when all of them have `&` XD Whatever, I can think this through theoretically.

Comment: Oh. Because the `instr` in your `trim` is reading the first half. Edit: so it only works if that is shorter than the second half. Edit2: you want to find the space after the `&` and do your `right` from there.

Comment: @findwindow comment upvotes don't earn you rep you know ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug ooohh so that's what I have been doing wrong XD

Comment: Why don't you just use the `Mid$()` function instead?

Comment: Because I didnt think of it till you mentioned it *blush*

Comment: haha fair enough - also I've updated your post to clarify the image as I this _really_ confused me!

Comment: Oh yea! `mid` with `find` duh XD Edit: ooohhhh the image is the source. Yea, super confusing.

Comment: sorry about that :( I will try and be super thorough next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Mid$()` instead:

```
this = Trim$(Mid$(Block1.Text, InStr(Block1.Text, "&") +  1))
```

Comment: Wait. What's the `$`?

Comment: It's a type character, methods like `Trim()`, `Left()`, `Mid()` etc. actually return a `Variant` - using the `$` type character implicitly casts the return value to a `String` which is faster to process. But in real life - probably not any noticeable difference. Okay, I'm a snob so what..

Comment: Removing upvote and downvoting and flagging for being a snob.

Comment: Totally worth it. I regret nothing.

Comment: Snobby and cocky are ok as long as you are awesome at whatever youre being arrogant about :D

Answer (score 1):

You're currently getting the position of `&` from the left of the string and then using this number to take the date from the right of the string; instead you should subtract the `Instr` value of `&` from the `Len` of the string in order to get your remaining characters. Try this:

```
Private Sub Block1_Enter()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim MyData As New DataObject
    Dim this As String
    Dim oldxt As String
    oldtxt = Block1.Text
    If InStr(Block1.Text, "&") > 0 Then
        this = Trim(Right(Block1.Text, (Len(Block1) - InStr(Block1.Text, "&") - 1))
        Block1.Text = "End Date Copied" & this
        MyData.SetText this
        MyData.PutInClipboard
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
        Block1.Text = oldtxt
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

The reason those dates in particular were errors was because the character length of the second date was shorter than the character length of the first date.

Comment: i will try this out and let you know how awesome you are in a bit

Comment: syntax error in you altered line. got it to work but i had to choose an answer and the mid function is actually what I ended up doing anyway,.